# Why does python pandas need fix infront of ax to draw a graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, series

I was learning how to make graphs with python pandas. But I couldn't understand how this code works.
`fig , ax = plt.subplots( ) ax = tips[['total_bill','tip']].plot.hist(alpha=0.5, bins=20, ax=ax)`

I couldn't understand why the code words only when there is fig infront of ax.
Also I have no idea what 'ax=ax' means.

I found everywhere but I couldn't find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is using the library `matplotlib` to do the plotting. Try to read up a bit about how matploltib works, it will help you understand this code a bit.

Generally, plotting with matplotlib involves a figure and one or more axes. A figure can be thought of as a frame where multiple plots can be created inside. Each plot consists of an axes object which contains your x- and y-axis and so on.

With the command `plt.subplots()`, you create in a single function a `figure` object and one or more `axes` objects. If you pass no parameters to the function, just a single `axes` object will get created that is placed on the `figure` object. The `figure` and `axes` are returned as a tuple by the function in the form of `(figure, axes)`. You are unpacking that tuple with the first line into the variable `fig` and `ax`.

Then, when you call the plotting function on your pandas data, you tell the function on which `axes` object to do the plotting. This is what the parameter `ax` means in that function. So you are telling the function to use your `axes` object that your variable `ax` is assigned to by setting the parameter `ax` to `ax` (`ax = ax`).

Doing `ax = tips[['total_bill','tip']].plot...` is redundant. The plotting function returns the `axes` object on which the plotting was performed by pandas. However, you are just overwriting your already existing `axes` with the returned `axes`, which in this case are the same object. This would only be needed if you don't pass the `ax` parameter to the plotting function, in which case pandas would create a brandnew `figure` and `axes` object for you and return the `axes` object in case you want to do any further tweaks to it.